# Почему order выводится в консоль и как его можно скрыть?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Order {
      constructor(id, weight) {
        this.id = id;
        this.weight = weight;
      }
    }

    class Truck extends Array {
      constructor(number, weightLimit) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.weightLimit = weightLimit;
      }

      add(order) {
        if (!this.isFit(order)) {
          return false;
        }
        this.push(order);
        return true;
      }

      isFit(order) {
        return this.weightLimit >= (this.totalWeight + order.weight);
      }

      get totalWeight() {
        return this.reduce((total, order) => total + order.weight, 0);
      }

      show() {
        console.log(`Машина №${this.number} (общий вес груза ${this.totalWeight}кг):`);
        this.forEach(order => console.log(`\tЗаказ #${order.id} ${order.weight}кг`));
      }
    }

    class TruckPlanner {
      constructor(weightLimit) {
        this.weightLimit = weightLimit;
        this.orders = [];
      }

      add(order) {
        this.orders.push(order)
      }

      *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let truck = new Truck(1, this.weightLimit);                
        for (let order of this.orders) {                           
          while (!truck.isFit(order)) {                            
            yield truck;                                           
            truck = new Truck(truck.number + 1, this.weightLimit); 
                    truck = new Truck(truck.number + 1, this.weightLimit);
          } 
          truck.add(order);                                        
        }
         yield truck;
      }
    }

    const planner = new TruckPlanner(10);
    planner.add(new Order(1, 2));
    planner.add(new Order(2, 4));
    planner.add(new Order(3, 4));
    planner.add(new Order(4, 4));
    planner.add(new Order(5, 1));
    planner.add(new Order(6, 2));


    console.log(planner.orders)
    for (const truck of planner) {
      truck.show();
    }
```

Comment: уберите все `console.log`

Comment: `console.log(planner.orders)` 4 строка снизу

Comment: Огромное спасибо, глаз замылился)